# Can I publish the same app both on app store and android market?

Tags: app-store, symbian, google-play

i have an application. I want to publish it on app store (iPhone/iPad platform) and Android market.

Is this possible? I mean, knowing Apple strange policy with this type of things, i was asking myself if publishing with app store will render legally impossible to publish it on another software market (android, symbian etc...). And what about Android market or Symbian market?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

You can publish the same app on both markets.

**Long Answer:**

Since android devices can't use iphone apps and vice versa the app will need to be written to work on both devices. If you write it in both devices respective languages then you can have the same app on both markets.

So write it twice and yes its easily possible.

Comment: I will not write it "twice", since i can use C/C++ on both platforms with minimal Objective C and Java use...So the app is basically the same: the name, the logo, the graphics, the mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just take a look in both stores: there are a lof of apps available for Apple and for Andriod. So it is possible.